# React List w/ JSON call? (FIDDLE)

Tags: json, reactjs

I"m trying to pull images into a React List module using a JSON and can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

This [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/kirkbross/69z2wepo/41878/) is supposed to grab two images from my server.

Code:

```
var Playlist = React.createClass({
  render() {
    var playlistImages = [];
    $.getJSON('http://k1r.com/json/playlist_tn.json', function(data){
        playlistImages = data;      
    });
    return (
        <List list={playlistImages.images} />
    )
  }
});
```

[UPDATED FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/kirkbross/69z2wepo/41886/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure you can use modules directly in JSFiddle, but apart from that the main issue is that you are fetching some asynchronous data directly in your render method and React isn't going to wait on that to finish before rendering your List.

The suggested approach (via the docs: https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/initial-ajax.html) is to make your data request inside of the componentDidMount or componentWillMount lifecycle methods then use setState() to trigger a re-render when the data has been received, which should then correctly render your List.

Comment: Thanks @BradColthurst... my React knowledge is very thin at this point, but I updated my FIDDLE (above) to what I think it should be. I also added an access-control header in my server root so it should serve my json file but I've clearly done something wrong as the 2 images aren't appearing.

Comment: There are still quite a few issues with the updated fiddle, like doing a GET request from https (jsfiddle) to http (where your JSON is located). It also looks like you're getting tripped up a bit on state vs props and how to structure your data and communicate across components.

Here's a working codepen that fakes the AJAX request with a setTimeout() and renders the data, I added some comments in there to help you out: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jqRWbz

Comment: Considerable thanks @BradColthurst. This really helps a lot. I've been trying to get handle on EXACTLY that: how and when to communicate across components. I'll be able to apply your example to myriad places in my project. Thanks again!

Comment: No problem. Happy to help!